# Is it possible to do a statement within a statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

So I'm trying to do something like this

```
if($id == 1 || $id == 2 || $id == 5 || $id == 8) {
echo 'test';
} elseif($id == 6) {
echo 'test2';
} else {
echo 'error';
}
```

It's so I can show a specific message (with html etc in the finished version) when the id obtained via post method is different.

EDIT: The issue is the code repeats itself twice.

How could I go about resolving this?

Thanks to anyone who contributes into helping me with this!

Comment: It is unclear what you want to know and what the problem is.

Comment: that code works

Comment: Sorry, it somewhat repeats the outcome on my side (which is the issue), any idea why

Comment: print your `$id` and check its value. If statement calls only once.

Comment: *"The issue is the code repeats itself twice."* -- what code repeats? In the final version the `if` blocks will display different output, isn't it?

Comment: Why not using switch case ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it repeats the outcome on my side*" ? Is it that you want to have only one `echo` **in your code** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$arr = [1,2,5,8];
$id = 1;
if(in_array($id, $arr)) {
    echo 'test';
} elseif($id == 6) {
    echo 'test2';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/T5giX

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. AS for everyone else, apologizes that I didn't make it as clear as possible - that's a fault at my end. I appreciate all of your assistance. I wanted to make it as short as I could as well, and this does it.

Comment: @MichaelMyers "***as well***" but what was the other condition to answer your question ? I still don't get it

Answer (score 0):

As i see you have more than 3 id to compare so easy Solution is take all id as an array
**And use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).**

```
<?php

    $id = 3;
    $myid = array(1,2,5,8);

        if(in_array($id,$myid)) {

          echo 'test';

        } elseif($id == 6) {

           echo 'test2';

        } else {

          echo 'error';

        }
```

**Also You Can Use [PHP Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp)**

```
<?php

$id = 6;


switch ($id) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 5:
    case 8:
        echo "Passed .!";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "Passwd 2!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Failed .!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make this statement in one line use ternary operator. hope it satisfy you.

```
echo ( ($id == 1 || $id == 2 || $id == 5 || $id == 8) ? "test" : (($id == 6) ? "test2" : "error"));
```

Comment: I don't think the user asked for a one-line solution. Actually, I believe this question is so unclear that none of the answers here is answering it